# pandas one row DF to dictionary including index value as key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

When filtering a DF with an index I would like to obtain a dictionary of records of the particular row filtered BUT INCLUDING the index itself.

So far I got:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'], 'b': [0.5, 0.25, 0.125],'c': [1,2,3]}).set_index('a')
df
df.loc[['red']].to_dict('records')[0]
```

gives:

```
{'b': 0.5, 'c': 1}
```

I would like the dictionary to include {'index':'red'}

I proceed as follows:

```
md = df.loc[['red']].to_dict('records')[0]
md.update({'index':'red'})
md
```

It works. so far so good.

BUT I would like to know why the following DOES NOT WORK:

```
md = df.loc[['red']].to_dict('records')[0].update({'index':'red'})
md
```

THIS PRINTS NOTHING
and type(md) gives none type

Comment: `df.loc[['red']].to_dict('records')[0]` returns a dictionary and using `update` occurs in-place. So you are updating the dictionary in place, which is why nothing is returned. So essentially all you are doing is `md = None` because in-place functions/methods return None.

Answer (score 2):

`df.loc[['red']].to_dict('records')[0].update({'index':'red'})` does not work as the dictionary `update` method works **in place** (and returns `None`).

You can [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.loc[['red']].reset_index().to_dict('records')[0]
```

output: `{'a': 'red', 'b': 0.5, 'c': 1}`

If you really want `index` as key:

```
df.rename_axis('index').loc[['red']].reset_index().to_dict('records')[0]
```

output: `{'index': 'red', 'b': 0.5, 'c': 1}`